# phonegap app with no touch screen on key events not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a web app that has no touch screen capability so for a user to
be able to move from one html to the other I need that the app will
identify an ENTER keypress and will load the .
however for some reason the onkeypress is not identified by android at
all. I get no response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function whichButton() {
alert("got a key = " + event.keyCode);
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
//code
}
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it with Android, but in BlackBerry [This JS](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/index.php) works like a real charm for browser testing and Phonegap. Besides, it is very easy to use and it is pretty well documented.

In your case, you need to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    shortcut.add("enter", functionToMoveToADifferentHTML,{
        'type':'keypress',
        'disable_in_input':true,
        'target':document
    });
</script>
```

The `type` is pretty obvious (it supports `keyup`, `keypress`, and `keydown`).
The `disable_in_input` with `true` allows the shortcut to be disabled when the focus is on a text field (extremely useful, by the way). The `target` defines the element that should be watched for the keyboard.